# combine multidimentional associative arrays with matching key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
 [traffic] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [visitors] => 310
                [pageviews] => 1333
                [created_date] => 2016-03-09
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [visitors] => 374
                [pageviews] => 1010
                [created_date] => 2016-03-10
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [visitors] => 143
                [pageviews] => 617
                [created_date] => 2016-03-11
            )

    )

[source] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [created_date] => 2016-03-09
                [scount] => 368
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [created_date] => 2016-03-10
                [scount] => 550
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [created_date] => 2016-03-11
                [scount] => 238
            )

    )
```

I have two multidimensional arrays, I want to combine both arrays into one with matching created_date value, the result should be like this,

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [created_date] => 2016-03-09
        [id] => 1
        [visitors] => 310
        [pageviews] => 1333
        [scount] => 368
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [created_date] => 2016-03-10
        [id] => 2
        [visitors] => 374
        [pageviews] => 1010
        [scount] => 550
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [created_date] => 2016-03-11
        [id] => 3
        [visitors] => 143
        [pageviews] => 617
        [scount] => 238
    )
```

)

Comment: created_date can be multiple or not ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$traffic = []; //...
$source = []; // ...

foreach($traffic as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($source[$key]))
    {
        $token = $source[$key];
        foreach($token as $keyy => $valuee)
        {
            if(isset($traffic[$key][$keyy]))
            {
                // Collision handling, if any ...
                $traffic[$key][$keyy] = $valuee;
            }
            else $traffic[$key][$keyy] = $valuee;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice namning of the second foreach loops key and value variables.

Comment: This code will fail if there are some change in both array keys eg: 0,1,2 and 1,2,3

Comment: It wont fail, it will work as expected. OP wants to merge based on their index key, so if they have different index key, they should not be merged

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick.

**The solution:**

```
# I split your array into 2 parts ($traffic = $your_array['traffic'])
$traffic = array(
  array(
    id => 1,
    visitors => 310,
    pageviews => 1333,
    created_date => '2016-03-09'
  ),
  array(
    id => 2,
    visitors => 374,
    pageviews => 1010,
    created_date => '2016-03-10'
  ),
  array(
    id => 3,
    visitors => 143,
    pageviews => 617,
    created_date => '2016-03-11'
  )
);

# I split your array into 2 parts ($source = $your_array['source'])
$source = array(
  array (
    created_date => '2016-03-09',
    scount => 368
  ),
  array (
    created_date => '2016-03-10',
    scount => 550
  ),
  array (
    created_date => '2016-03-11',
    scount => 238
  )
);

# copy the traffic array cause we want to merge the new data into it
$result = $traffic;

# loop over the traffic array
foreach ($traffic as $k => $t) {

  # loop over the source
  foreach ($source as $s) {

    # try to find a match
    if ($t['created_date'] === $s['created_date']) {

      # add data to result
      $result[$k]['scount'] = $s['scount'];

      # we exit the inner foreach-loop here as there is only 1 match
      break;
    }
  }
}

# print the result
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

**The result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [visitors] => 310
            [pageviews] => 1333
            [created_date] => 2016-03-09
            [scount] => 368
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [visitors] => 374
            [pageviews] => 1010
            [created_date] => 2016-03-10
            [scount] => 550
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [visitors] => 143
            [pageviews] => 617
            [created_date] => 2016-03-11
            [scount] => 238
        )

)
```

you can test it here: [http://www.writephponline.com](http://www.writephponline.com/)

Answer (score 0):

***Here is your solution***:-

```
$arr1 = $arr1['traffic']; // assign key traffic record to array1
$arr2 = $arr2['source'];  // assign key source record to array2
$result = [];
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$value){     
    $result[$key] = $value;
    // find created_date in second array
    $keyOfSecondArr = array_search($value['created_date'], array_column($arr2, 'created_date'));
    $result[$key]['scount'] = $arr2[$keyOfSecondArr]['scount'];
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [visitors] => 310
            [pageviews] => 1333
            [created_date] => 2016-03-09
            [scount] => 368
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [visitors] => 374
            [pageviews] => 1010
            [created_date] => 2016-03-10
            [scount] => 550
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [visitors] => 143
            [pageviews] => 617
            [created_date] => 2016-03-11
            [scount] => 238
        )

)
```